# Which tool should I use to extract data from string?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

As a quite new Linux user I never (really) used tools such as `sed` and `awk` (or any others) to parse text.
I want to extract from

> Speed : 1624.127424 Kib/s in 9.410000 seconds

the time value in second, just before the `seconds` word ,

Which tool should I look into for this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of tools you could use, but [`awk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) will do fine:

```
echo "Speed : 1624.127424 Kib/s in 9.410000 seconds" | awk '{print $6}'
```

or (if your data is in a file):

```
awk '{print $6}' data.txt
```

gives you

```
9.410000
```

*Explanation*:

This assumes that the relative position of the value you are interested in on the line will stay the same (and in this case be the 6th white-space separated field), adjust accordingly.

`awk` splits the input line up into fields based on white-space. The field you are interested in is the 6th field, so you are printing that with `$6`.

Alternatively, you could have also used `awk '{print $(NF-1)}'` to print the next-to-last field on the line (`NF` is an awk variable that knows the number of fields on a given line). This offers a bit more flexibility as it would work with an length line (ie number of fields) as long as the field you were interested in was next-to-last).

--

[`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) would be another tool that would work too:

```
echo "Speed : 1624.127424 Kib/s in 9.410000 seconds" | cut -d' ' -f 6
```

in this case, the line is split based on the delimiter of space (as specified by `-d`) and again, we are interested in the 6th field (`-f 6`).

There are other ways too, but these two seem straight forward and came to mind first.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you don't know exactly where in the string it is but you know it's before the word 'seconds', you can use `sed`.  This gets into regular expressions, which aren't as straightforward as just counting fields, but they let you grab data out of strings that might not have such rigidly-constrained formats.  Here's one way (the `<<<` is just another way to feed a string as input to a command):

```
sed -n 's/^.* \([0-9.]\+\) seconds.*$/\1/p'  <<<"Speed : 1624.127424 Kib/s in 9.410000 seconds"
```

Since there's only one line of input, the `-n` and `/p` are extraneous here, but they form a useful pattern: they tell `sed` not to print out all the lines by default, but only the ones where the search and replace succeeds.

The `s/old/new/` syntax carries out a search and replace, where the 'old' part is a regular expression pattern.

The pattern `[0-9.]\+ seconds` matches one or more digits-or-periods followed by a space and the word "seconds".  Putting backslashed parentheses around part of the pattern causes the actual string that matches that part of the pattern to be saved in a variable for later use; so `\([0-9.]\+\) seconds` captures the desired number.

Since we want to print *only* that value, we put it between `^.*`, which matches 'everything from the beginning of the line', and `.*$`, which matches 'everything until the end of the line'.  That way the entire line will be replaced.  However, since `.*` is greedy, if we put it in front of the pattern, it will chew up all but the last digit of our number, which we don't want.  Adding the space before the number to the pattern prevents that.

What do we replace the line with?  With `\1`, which is the string that matched the part of the pattern between the (first pair of) backslash-parentheses.

**EDITED TO ADD:**

Perl isn't listed in the question, but a similar tack to the above `sed` approach would be this:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /([0-9.]+) seconds/'  <<<"Speed : 1624.127424 Kib/s in 9.410000 seconds"
```

Comment: You might consider adding the perl -pe version, that doesn't have all of those backslashes. Just to offer the OP  a few options with the regex technique.

Comment: perl -ne, in this case, @claytonstanley, but done.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single string in a variable, the shell itself can be used. If you know it is the sixth field (like @Levon's awk solution assumes), you can do this:

```
set -- $variable
seconds=$6
```

Or if you know the word is followed by the word `seconds`, you can use string replacements;

```
prefix=${variable%\ seconds*}
seconds=${prefix##*\ }
```

(The temporary variable contains the original with anything after space, "seconds" trimmed off. The we similarly trim everything up through the last space from the beginning of that.)

Don't under-estimate the shell, it is quite versatile, albeit sometimes quirky.

Comment: Neat shell tricks, esp the 2nd. Since I primarily use `tcsh` I personally prefer "shell-agnostic" solutions. `bash` solutions don't always work for me (but of course would not be a problem for OP since they tagged with bash)

Comment: Nothing particularly tied to Bash here, though. The double ## (longest match) might not be supported by really old Bourne shells, but anything reasonably POSIX should handle this, I believe.

Comment: Cool .. thanks for the additional information, I'll have to check this out under `tcsh`. Always good to have several ways to accomplish a given task.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completion, perl can operate in a awk-like mode. Assuming your data is in, well `data.txt`.

```
$ perl -lane 'print $F[5] data.txt'
9.410000
```

`-a` turns on autosplit mode – perl will automatically split input lines on whitespace into the @F array.

Answer (score 1):

Also, `cut`.

```
echo "Speed : 1624.127424 Kib/s in 9.410000 seconds" | cut -f 6 -d' '
```

Documentation (excerpt):

> `cut` - remove sections from each line of files
>
> **`-d, --delimiter=DELIM`**
>
> use `DELIM` instead of `TAB` for field delimiter
>
> **`-f, --fields=LIST`**
>
> select only these fields; also print any line that contains no delimiter character, unless the `-s` option is specified

Answer (score 0):

3 really weird ways to use `awk` via `RS` ::

```
echo 'Speed : 1624.127424 Kib/s in 9.410000 seconds' |
```

---

```
nawk 'END { print }'  RS='[^0-9.]+'
gawk  NF=NF==2 RS='.* in '
mawk  NF       RS='.* in |[^0-9.]+'
```

---

```
9.410000
```